# Restroom signs in Poland

Tags: poland, toilets

I've recently noticed that restroom signs in Poland can be an inverted triangle and a circle for the men's room and the ladies' room, respectively. These signs are completely foreign to me and I was wondering what's the reason behind the choice of these particular symbols and if they are also common in other countries?

[image]

Comment: A quick google showed that there are explanations from anatomy to astrology, but no definitive explanation that I can find.  However, I did see reference to similar symbols being seen in Germany and Lithuania.

Comment: @PeterM I have lived in Germany for 35 years and don't remember these types of signs at all

Comment: @Hilmar I was just reporting on some comments I found on a reddit thread when I was  googling the topic.  I remember it being suggested that it might be localized.

Comment: Which is which?

Comment: @badjohn triangle is male, circle is female.

Comment: Triangle is supposed to be exagerrated male silhouette. However, the use of a circle is a mystery, or a very grim outlook of female body structure.

Comment: Very interesting. In ancient Babylonia, a triangle pointing downwards was a female symbol...

Answer (score 1):

I <s>don't</s> didn't think there's anything specific to Poland here, fancy bars and the like have been experimenting with toilet signage for years.  The [Wikipedia article on gender symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_symbol) mentions that △/□ for male and circle ○ for female are used in genealogy, so this is likely cribbed from there, although (somewhat to my surprise!) the same article also notes that this is particularly common in Poland.

Random anecdote: around 15 years ago, I recall visiting a painfully hip bar in Bangkok that simplified things even further to a ◯ for women and a | for men, and jazzed things up a bit more with ice cubes in the urinal, producing visible steam in the tropical night.  At least here the [symbolism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_of_connectors_and_fasteners) is fairly obvious.